# js number +1 problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need click `div.toggle1`,control slideup, slidedown the `div#text1`,

click `div.toggle7`,control slideup, slidedown the `div#text7`.

here is my code, also in http://jsfiddle.net/qHY8K/  my `number +1` not work, need a help. thanks.

html

```
<div class="toggle1">click</div>
<div id="text1">text1</div>
<div class="toggle7">click</div>
<div id="text7">text2</div>
```

js code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
counter = 0;
    for(i=1;i<11;i++){
        (function(i){
            counter = counter +1;
            $('.toggle'+counter).toggle(function(){
                $('#text'+counter).css('display','none');
            },
            function() {
                $('#text'+counter).css('display','block');
            });
        })(i);
    };  
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets simplify things a bit. One of the nice things about jQuery is that you can apply an event handler to many elements all at the same time. Start by adding a common classname to all of your 'toggle' divs:

#### HTML

```
<div class="toggle toggle1">click</div>
<div id="text1">text1</div>
<div class="toggle toggle7">click</div>
<div id="text7">text2</div>
```

Now you can use just one selector to target all of those divs. The rest is just a matter of pulling out the numeric difference in each 'toggle' div's classname:

#### JavaScript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $('.toggle').toggle(off, on);

    function on() {
        var i = this.className.match(/[0-9]+/)[0];
        $('#text'+i).css('display','block');
    }

    function off() {
        var i = this.className.match(/[0-9]+/)[0];
        $('#text'+i).css('display','none');
    }
});
```

I've updated your jsFiddle project. Hopefully this works out for you: http://jsfiddle.net/ninjascript/qHY8K/3/

Comment: I will say, it is a nice code, do not need a loop never, Thanks.

Comment: Very fragile, though. If he adds *any other class* with a digit it it to any of the toggle divs, it fails. Can fix that with the regexp.

Answer (score 3):

Two solutions:

1. With your HTML as quoted, you can just do this:

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       $("div.toggle").click(function() {
           $(this).next().toggle();
       });
   });
   ```

   ...since the div you're toggling is the next adjacent div. Note also that I'm using jQuery's `toggle` function to toggle the visibility.

   But if it's possible that may change and you're defending against that, read on...
2. In your JavaScript code, you're already doing something that makes it possible to avoid the `counter` entirely, as [knitti pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049267/js-number-1-problem/7049285#7049285). But the way you're doing it creates functions unnecessarily and by using the same name (`i`) for both your loop counter and the argument to your anonymous function, you're making it very difficult to read and maintain that code.

   So:

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {

       for(i=1;i<11;i++){
           makeToggler(i);
       }

       function makeToggler(index){
           $('.toggle'+index).click(function(){
               $('#text'+index).toggle();
           });
       }
   });
   ```

   You can see how nice and clear that makes things, and in particular using a different name for the loop counter and the argument to `makeToggler` avoids confusion. And again, using jQuery's `toggle` function, no need for you to do it at the click level. (Also note that you don't put `;` after the ending brace of a `for` statement.)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need hard coded loop.

Preserve your current HTML and have such jQuery code instead:

```
$("div[class^='toggle']").each(function() {
    var num = $(this).attr("class").replace("toggle", "");
    $(this).toggle(function(){
        $('#text' + num).css('display','none');
    },
    function() {
        $('#text' + num).css('display','block');
    });
});
```

This will iterate over all the `<div>` elements with class name starting with `toggle` and attach them the proper `toggle` function.

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qHY8K/5/

Comment: This is also a nice function, even do not need a `.match`

Answer (score 1):

why do you introduce a new variable `counter`? (you should use `var counter = 0;` if you do).

in your function you could simply use your copied loop variable `i`:

```
for(i=1;i<11;i++){
    (function(i){
        $('.toggle'+i).toggle(function(){
            $('#text'+i).css('display','none');
        },
        function() {
            $('#text'+i).css('display','block');
        });
    })(i);
};
```

Comment: +1, but the `i` in question is *not* the loop variable, it's the argument to the construction function. And it really, really matters. :-)

Comment: @tjcrowder: ah yeah… you are right of course. but the anonymous function is quite unnecessary in this piece of code

Comment: @knitti: Actually, it's essential (although making it anonymous and repeatedly creating it isn't necessary and is not best practice). Otherwise your solution has the same problem his original does, the event handler closures have an *enduring reference* to `i`, not a *copy* of it as of when they're created. So when the events occur, **all** of the handlers will try to operate on an element (`text11`) that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

If your HTML has the structure as above, you could give all the `toggleX` elements the same class `toggle` and then all you have to do is:

```
$('.toggle').toggle(function(){
    $(this).next().css('display','none');
},
function() {
    $(this).next().css('display','block');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qHY8K/6/)